# MEAN Stack: How to handle internationalization in front end error messages?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, internationalization

I am using a MEAN stack (mongodb, express, angular, nodejs) to develop an application. To render HTML in different languages I am using the i18n-2 node module.

But, I have some front end error messages (like validation errors - eg. Invalid Email). These messages appear based on user actions. How can these messages be internationalized?

One approach I can think of is to use hidden elements in jade / html and then pull out the same in angular / javascript. Alternatively, I can pass some ng-init variables in the jade file and then pull out the appropriate message at runtime in the angular controller.

Is the above approach ok? Or is there any other best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Angular Translate module:

http://angular-translate.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Angular Auto Validate module:

http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/

You could combine it with the Angular Translate module and create a custom error message resolver.

Comment: Thanks Jon Samwell, this appears to be a nice module that I may use in my project anyway. However, now I have a new related question. Which is better to use for internationalization - Angular Translate (kinda front end driven i18n) or i18n for node (where html pages are i18ed in backend)? I think i18n for node looks much cleaner.

Comment: I think it depends how you want to approach i18n.  In a few large projects I have done that are multi tenanted the resource strings have been stored in DB tables.  During the build process I turn thoses strings into resource files per modules i.e. auth-lang-fr.json which I then download on the client when needed and change text in the template.  If you are getting your templates from the server I would probably do it on the server.  However I pre-package the modules templates into the JS during the build phase to reduce http request and make the application smoother/quicker.